# What is Bootstrapping in statistics? How can I use it to determine error in the mean, variance, kurtosis and skewness of a data set?

Tags: variance, bootstrap, standard-error, resampling, kurtosis

From what I understood from searching randomly is that it has something to do with resampling. What does this resampling mean? Is it selecting random data from a distribution or is it getting data from somewhere else?

Comment: I think you should google a bit more....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrapping, very briefly, means that you repeatedly resample (with replacement) from the data you have and compute a statistic on each sample. Then you combine the statistics

However, many entire books have been written on bootstrapping.

Comment: I'll add that Efron and Tibshirani's book is marvelously written and great fun to read.

Comment: There is some ambiguity in this answer: exactly what is being "combined" at the end?  Samples?  "Estimated" statistics? (Don't you really mean *compute* instead of *estimate*?) In any case, *how* would the combination be done and for what purpose?